# GeoJSON file making leaflet API slow site down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to use the leaflet API to display data about Coral Reef locations across the world. I originally downloaded a shapefile (.shp), and converted it to GeoJSON using QGIS. I put the data in my project folder, but when I attempted to display this data on leaflet through an Ajax request, the browser took a very long time to load and eventually return a not responding message. However, I could see that the markers would appearing on the map, albeit it very slowly. Is there any way to create a smaller file, or load the data more efficiently so it doesn't make the entire site unusable?

My Ajax request looked like this:

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './coldwater.geojson',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            L.geoJSON(data).addTo(mymap);
        }, error: function(){
            console.log('Couldn\'t load data');
        }
    });
```

Here's a snippet of the geoJSON

```js
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -75.116700000304718, 18.283300000094982 ], [ -75.116699858211859, 18.283301156623111 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -34.850000000399632, 9.01670000040474 ], [ -34.849996660317572, 9.016695959750791 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -34.850000000399632, 9.01670000040474 ], [ -34.849996660317572, 9.016695959750791 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -81.166699999905006, 23.983300000394763 ], [ -81.166699953140267, 23.983303104854429 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -79.549997733808311, 26.649999766076405 ], [ -79.416700222836994, 27.166696245435446 ], [ -79.416700222836994, 27.283302340130945 ], [ -79.416699999805132, 27.283300000094982 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -78.683303107752181, 27.416698775628049 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -79.216699996607531, 24.099999131754601 ], [ -78.850001440414133, 26.516702255105031 ], [ -78.39999868309269, 26.583297050818317 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -77.083301298815854, 25.166702977260627 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -79.233301481578053, 27.216698550297906 ], [ -79.216699996607531, 27.300002749627254 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -79.549997733808311, 26.649999766076405 ], [ -79.416700222836994, 27.166696245435446 ], [ -79.416699999805132, 27.166700000104981 ], [ -79.366697917974477, 27.533295877103114 ] ] } },
```

Would it be better to use the google maps API? 
Or is there a better way to insert a shapefile into a leaflet map?

ps: if this isn't appropriate or is off topic let me know. I'm new to posting on stackoverflow

Comment: What order of magnitude of objects are there in the GeoJSON?

Comment: @peeebeee I'm not sure but I'll add a snippet of a little of the file

Comment: Do please make an estimate of how many objects you're asking Leaflet to draw. Is it tens, hundreds, or millions? The answer will dictate the solution.

Comment: @peeebeee I believe in the hundreds